# wpf toolkit rating size

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, wpftoolkit

I'm using a rating control (from wpf toolkit) in my application. Is there any way I can scale this control? The rating stars are too big for my application..

I tried setting the height or width but that just cuts the stars but doens't resize them:

```
Rating ratingControl = new Rating();
ratingControl .ItemsSource = ratingItems;
ratingControl.Width = 50;
ratingControl.Height = 10;
// --> this doesn't change the size of the stars
```

Greets Daan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i dont know the rating control, but if you wanna scale something in wpf you can simply use ScaleTransform

```
  <Rating>
      <Rating.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.8" ScaleY="0.8"></ScaleTransform>
        </Rating.LayoutTransform>
   </Rating>
```

Comment: I didn't think of that! Thank you for the answer. I translated this into: ratingControl.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(0.5,0.5); and it workeld like a charm.

Comment: When trying this on Windows Phone, there didn't seem to be a LayoutTransform present; in that case, I used the above code, but with a RenderTransform instead.

Comment: This is a brilliant, commonly overlooked solution.