# WPF Toolkit Rating control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I'm using WPF Toolkit "Rating" control.In that, How can i reduce the star size?
If i reduce width and height then the stars are not fully visible.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this topic. The question was already tackeld in it

[wpf toolkit rating size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312934/wpf-toolkit-rating-size?rq=1)